# How to define the behavior of a node before creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I run some scripts on specific elements after their creation automatically. For example there is a jquery plugin named autoresize that can expand the height of an textarea. If I run `$('.textarea').autosize()` only current textareas will be affected. And I have to rerun the code each time I create a textarea manually.

`MuttaionObserver` could be a solution. But I think it is overkill.

Update:
Also I found https://github.com/fschaefer/jquery-behavior any idea?

Comment: Use event delegation?

Comment: Just call the method on the new textarea: `$(newTextarea).autosize();`

Comment: @FelixKling I am lookknig for automatic solution.

Comment: You'll need to instantiate the plugin for any new elements you add each time you add them. I suggest making a single function that does both operations so you only need to call one thing.

Comment: you won't find any other solution that will work cross browser

Comment: @megawac May you please provide an example?

Comment: If you want to listen event of new insert dom without reattach the event handler, you can do that with event delegation. If you want to monitor DOM change, then run certain function that's not going to happen cross browser I think. You should rerun you function every time you insert new element.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that creates the element, then adds it to your DOM. Then, apply your plugin on the newly created element.

```
function addTextarea()
{
    $("<textarea>")
        .appendTo(YOUR_PARENT_NODE)
        .autosize();
}
```